# Check if a point is in the good or bad part of Yin and Yan ( coordination system ) C++

Tags: c++

I have an issue with my program. The point is to enter the coordinates of x and y and the program to calculate if they are in the Good/Evil/Neutral part of the Yin and Yan symbol.

The issue is in the middle circles , when entering x = 2.5 and y = 3 It shows Evil when it ought to print Good. Can not find an issue in my code.

```
}
//medium circle above the abscissa
if (((x*x + pow(y - 6, 2)) < 9) ) {
    cout << "Good" << endl;
    return 0;

//medium circle under the abscissa 
if ((x*x + pow(y+6,2)) < 9) {
    cout << "Evil" << endl;
    return 0;
}

`
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code line by line in a debugger? Have you tried to do the calculations by hand on paper to see the expected results? How do the expected results compare to the actual results in the program?

Comment: For what reason should 2.5, 3.0 be good?

Answer (score 1):

The small and medium circles have their centres in the same spot, `(0, ±3)`, but you're moving `y` six units for the medium one.

Comment: That solved it. My bad , I guess I was looking at the radius , not the distance when typing it. Thank you